# appending lists to an existing excel file starting from a specific cells with Python, Openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, openpyxl

I'm getting no of list's in `my_list` and want to add list's item in excel from `cell E3`
to length of `my_list` cell `cell (AI8)`

```
print(my_list)
```

```
['W', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'W', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'W', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'W', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'W', 'Mon', 'Tue']
['Sun', 'W', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'W', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'W', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'W', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'W', 'Tue']
['Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W']
['Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W']
['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'W', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'W', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'W', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'W', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue']
```

And I want add like this image replace other items like `mon, tue, wed` with None and add just `W`

[image]

My Code is

```
for r in range(4, 9):
    for c,val in zip(5, my_list):
        ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value=val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through the Excel range by cell, and use the cell positon to find the value in the list then write to the cell if the value returned from the list is 'W'.
Adjust the range max/min rows to suit the actual rows.

```
import openpyxl

my_list = [['W', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'W', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'W', 'Mon',
            'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'W', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'W', 'Mon', 'Tue'],
           ['Sun', 'W', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'W', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'W',
            'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'W', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'W', 'Tue'],
           ['Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon',
            'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W'],
           ['Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon',
            'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'W'],
           ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'W', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'W', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon',
            'Tue', 'W', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'W', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue']]

filename = 'foo.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

start_column = 5
for enum, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_col=start_column, max_col=35, min_row=4, max_row=8)):
    for cell in row:
        listval = my_list[enum][cell.column - start_column]
        if listval == 'W':
            cell.value = listval

wb.save('foo_out.xlsx')
```

Comment: hey thanks @moken I have just one question where did you learn this and how  please tell me i want to learn python and do code like you

Comment: If you use `zip` over the lists and rows you don't need to enumerate.

Comment: @Sagar Patil learn the programing basics for python; lists, loops, conditional statements etc.. there are a number of free tutorial sites like www.w3schools.com, pythonGeeksforgeeks, pythontutorial, Udemy. Go through the tutorials and examples understand how they work. As you get an understanding of how the basics work you can look on sites like SO for real world uses in the areas that interest you. Look at the questions in SO and answers and try to understand how these work. Then try to answer the questions yourself (you dont have to post your answer, just do as your own exercise).

Comment: The questions do not need to be the latest, you can go back through the last few years. Compare how you've solved both the question both in the approach and actual code compared to the other answers, there is usually more than one way to solve an issue. Remember the accepted answer is not necessarily the best and new [better] methods to achieve that the asker wants may be added to the question over time. If your happy with your answer feel free to post even if other answers have already been posted. Dont be discouraged by negative feedback if it happens.